# Как сделать цикл выбора?

Tags: python, requests

Хочу чтобы я вводил да или нет, и в зависимости от ответа будет выбираться цикл. Если нет то спрашивается лог и пароль и отправляет запрос для входа, а если да то спрашивается лог и пароль и отправляется запрос на сервер мол мы регистрируемся и затем сразу вход с данными которые мы ввели.

```
print('Вы новый пользователь?')
    otvet = input()
    if otvet == 'да' or 'Да':
        l = input('Логин: ')
        p = input('Пароль: ')
        reg = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/reg?login={l}&password={p}')
        print(reg.text)
        log = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/login?login={l}&password={p}')
        print(log.text)
    elif otvet == 'нет' or 'Нет':
        l1 = input('Логин: ')
        p1 = input('Пароль: ')
        log1 = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/login?login={l1}&password={p1}')
        print(log1.text)
```

Вот что получилось у меня но почему то это не работает.

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
        print('Вы новый пользователь?')
        otvet = str(input())
        if otvet == 'да':
            l = input('Логин: ')
            p = input('Пароль: ')
            reg = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/reg?login={l}&password={p}')
            print(reg.text)
            log = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/login?login={l}&password={p}')
            print(log.text)
            break
        elif otvet == 'нет':
            l = input('Логин: ')
            p = input('Пароль: ')
            log1 = requests.get(f'http://{ser}/login?login={l}&password={p}')
            print(log1.text)
            break
        else:
            print('да или нет')
```

Comment: это ответ или дополнение/корректировка вопроса?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ответ

Comment: тогда, ожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]